# Creating a fake clock whose data can be accessed from another thread

Tags: java

I want to build an extension of TimerTask that runs in a continual loop (ie. as a fake clock), but I need the 'time' to be accessible from other methods.

I've managed to get the clock going so it runs fine, and will print back the 'correct' time to the console from within the clock loop. But whenever I try to access the hours/days/years on the fake clock from a different method, it prints back the original initialization value of 0 days, 0 months, 0 years...even when the clock itself is further along as seen in the console view, ie. 5 days, 6 months, 9 years.

My TimerTask increments as below (but for all of hour, day, month, year):
        if (currenthour == 24) {
            currenthour = 0;
            currentday++;
        }
At the end of the loop, I'm putting the thread to sleep for 1000 ms to slow it down.

I suspect this has to do with thread locks? But can't seem to find a way to prove/disprove that theory, or to fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you make the fields `volatile`? Variables are taken inside a thread's local data, and only synchronized when a field is volatile.

Comment: You don't need to create a fake copy just to read, or even make the fields `volatile`. However, do as Joop said if you wish to write in those fields.

Comment: Consider using a ScheduledExecutorService. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html It's far better than Thread.sleep for regularly scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, which had nothing to do with threads. I'd created a second instantiation of the object which was being read instead.